# What does rm -rf $(!!) mean on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I know rm -rf is a force deletion on everything in a given directory. But I don’t understand what rm -rf $(!!) will do on the command line.

How can I look up this syntax or understand what it will do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `!!` is a history command of `bash`, it gets replaced by the last command you‘ve executed. You can try `ls` followed by `echo !!`
- `$(...)` performs Command Substitution, the output of a command replaces the command name (the part within the `()`). Again, `echo $(!!)` helps to illustrate this

So `rm $(!!)` removes all files whose names are printed after re-running the last command. Watch out for file names containing spaces or special characters like `*` or `?` or `~`; it won‘t work for those, or it will remove a different set of files than you’d think.

Given the risks it's probably safer to run `echo PATTERN`, verify the result and then go back one line in the history, replace `echo` by `rm` and execute this. Instead of navigating back you can also just run `^echo^rm^` (which uses history expansion to replace the command used in the line before).

Comment: I can see no good reason to ever use `rm -rf $(!!)`, can you? It just seems dangerous. Perhaps worth stating explicitly, if you agree.

Comment: @innisfree: I'd agree with that.  If you want to check your rm command first, do `echo rm foo/* bar` or whatever, then recall it and remove the `echo ` from the front.  Doing `ls foo/* bar` then `rm -rf $(!!)` sounds like a terrible idea.  e.g. if `bar/x` exists, that sequence will remove `./x`

Comment: @innisfree Valid point, added an alternative approach.